# Java Making toolbar visible

Tags: java, eclipse

Main toolbar is hidden.

No save and save all print.
This appear only in the File menu.

I want to have all the options. How do i get it?

[image: My eclipce]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the hidden toolbar of Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301637/how-to-show-the-hidden-toolbar-of-eclipse)

Comment: the solution there doesnt work for me.. possibol bug?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE-> Window-> Show Tool bar
[image]

**UPDATE:** [Eclipse community working on this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432686)

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Comment: what do i need to click in the link above?

Comment: You do not need to do any thing eclipse community currently working on this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65516/discussion-between-sagar-pudi-and-stav-alfi).